# Counting Occurrence of Specific Character

Tags: python-3.x

I am having some trouble producing output from some code I wrote. I am using a .txt file, and want to count how many times a specific character occurs. I do not get any error messages when I run it, but no output is produced. I am using Windows 10 and the cmd.exe program, and running Python 3. Does anyone have any advice as to how to improve this? Thank you for any advice!
Here is my code so far:

```
input_file = sys.argv[1]
open (sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-8')

from collections import Counter
for line in sys.argv[1]:
    if ('blabla' in line):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-8')

for line in f:
    if ('blabla' in line):
        print(line)
```

You were iterating over the file name, instead of the file contents. (You opened the file but never used it.)

BTW, to make sure you properly close the file, this is the preferred pattern:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'blabla' in line:
            print(line)
```